# How to import a module with a dotted path?

Tags: python, import, module

I want to import the **paramiko** module located in **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages**. So, I imported it this way:

```
from usr.local.lib.python2.7.dist-packages import paramiko
```

I have an error syntax related to python2.7 (It considers 7 as a package located in python2 package)
I have both Python3.1.3 and Python2.7 installed. I program with Python3.1.3 only, however.
How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: does simply `import paramiko` not work? anything in that directory is an installed library, which is to say there should be a global reference in your python environment. Unless of course you put it there yourself rather than installing it..

Comment: Because I am using Python3.1.3. Only Python2.7 which is the default Python version on my system can import paramiko directly without the full path.

Comment: Oh my mistake, totally missed the Py3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you think you need to include the full path. That directory will already be included in the Python path. You just need to do `import paramiko`.

**Edit after comment** Well you can't randomly import things that are installed for a different version. There are several backwards incompatibilities, and anything that has any compiled extensions will just not work at all.

You need to download and install paramiko for your 3.1 installation, rather than trying to use the 2.7 version. `python3 pip install paramiko`, as an example.

(Also, you shouldn't really be using 3.1. If you're using the Python 3 series you should upgrade to 3.4.)

Comment: I installed Python3.1.3, so by default I can use what you suggest in Python2.7 which is the default on my system, but for Python3.1.3 I have to name the full path

Comment: thank you very much for highlighting that for me. But for special reasons, I am not allowed to upgrade my python version from 3.1.3 to higher.

Answer (score 2):

How about ?

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
import paramiko
```

**UPDATED**

The best solution is installing `paramiko` on Python3 env. Take a look at @DanielRoseman's answer. Or `virtualenv` is worth consideration. Here is a good tutorial. http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/